# merge csv lines if not ending with a pipe

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a rather large csv file where each line should end with a pipe (|) and if it doesn't combine the next line into it until find a pipe again. This need to done using a shell script.

I got an answer as

```
awk '!/|$/{l=l""$0|next|}{print l""$0|l=""}' file
```

But it gives me error as size of each line is quite large for me. I found out that I should be using perl to do that and have tried something as below but it does produce the desired result.

```
perl -pe 's/^\n(|\n)/ /gs' input.csv > output.csv
```

My data looks like

```
A|1|abc|<xml/>|
|2|def|<xml
>hello world</xml>|
|3|ghi|<xml/>|
```

And the desired output should be

```
A|1|abc|<xml/>|
|2|def|<xml>hello world</xml>|
|3|ghi|<xml/>|
```

Obviously the line size is quite large than the sample input here.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
perl -lne 'unless(/\|$/){$line=$line.$_}else{print $line." $_";undef $line}' your_file
```

if you want to do an inplace replacement do this:

```
perl -i -lne 'unless(/\|$/){$line=$line.$_}else{print $line." $_";undef $line}' your_file
```

check [here](http://ideone.com/YmHlud) regarding your comment

Comment: Sorry, I have now corrected it. Its a pipe I am looking for. trying your solution just now.

Comment: Your solution works small issue though, if all the rows end with a pipe (|), the script doesn't output anything where I want to print the lines as it is if they don't require any change.

Comment: you are wrong.its working even if all the lines end with a pipe.check here:http://ideone.com/YmHlud

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{printf "%s",$0} /[|][[:space:]]*$/ {print ""}'
```

Print every line without a newline. If the last non-whitespace character is a pipe, you have a complete line so print a newline.

Comment: awk was giving record size error, and I believe it can't handle large lines.

Comment: How large are the lines? Millions of characters?

Comment: yep it can easily go upto a million as the csv files I am using as input are the result of database export from a table that has HUGECLOB as data type. Thanks for your helps anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This should happily handle all cases for you, and not break on any line length:

```
#!/bin/bash
newLine=0
IFS=
while read -r -n 1 char; do
    if [[ $char =~ ^$ ]]; then
        if [[ $newLine -eq 1 ]]; then
            newLine=0
            echo '|' # add a newline
        fi  
    elif [[ $char =~ . && ( $newLine -eq 1 ) ]]; then
        newLine=0
        echo -n "|$char"
    elif [[ $char =~ [|] ]]; then
        if [[ $newLine -eq 1 ]]; then
            echo -n '|'
        fi  
        newLine=1
    else
        echo -n $char
    fi  
done < file.txt
```

Please note that building a lexer by hand in bash is usually a bad idea.